# Attempting to fetch and update a specific Core Data entity within master-detail view

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, ipad, core-data

I'm trying to fetch the specific instance of an item in a list but I can't recall the best way to do so. This is in the detail view of a master-detail list that when text changes end, it updates the item in the master list. However, I cant seem to get it to update the correct item, I know it lies in this part of my code:

```
guard let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate else {
                    return
                }
                let context = appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext

                let fetchRequest: NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult> = NSFetchRequest.init(entityName: "Event")

                do {

                    let test = try context.fetch(fetchRequest)
                    let objectUpdate = test[0] as! NSManagedObject
                    objectUpdate.setValue(noteText.text, forKey: "title")
                    do {
                        try context.save()
                    }
                } catch {
                    let nserror = error as NSError
                    fatalError("Unresolved error \(nserror), \(nserror.userInfo)")
                }
```

Specifically this part:

```
let test = try context.fetch(fetchRequest)
                        let objectUpdate = test[0] as! NSManagedObject
                        objectUpdate.setValue(noteText.text, forKey: "title")
```

**EDIT:**

I forgot to post the question! Basically with this current method, when I finish typing in the text field (this is wrapped in a `textFieldDidEndEditing` function) it saves, but at the lowest item in the master tableview. I want it to update the item that was selected.

Since I'm trying to grab the item from the tableview and update it, what is the best method for this? I'm assuming that I need to identify the correct item, but I'm not sure of the best method for this.

Comment: Hi, your question is very confused. 
what the problem you want solved?

Comment: @RamiresNascimento Sorry, I forgot to pose the issue. I will update the post.

Comment: Presumably you have an array of items as the datasource for your table.  Are they managed objects?  (If so, you only need to update the object matching the row and save rather than re-fetching it.)

Comment: @PhillipMills yes it is, I'm just not sure how to do that. I'm still rather new to coredata and managing it

Comment: I can't tell how the code you posted is related to item selection so I'll be a bit vague. When you select an item for editing, you want to remember the item or a way to identify it (index path?).  Then make it your  `objectUpdate`, change the value, and save the context.

Comment: @PhillipMills I ended up fixing it, I made a call for the coredata object as a variable, then passed it through with a segue. then all i needed to do was make `selectedNote?.title` = `noteText.text`

Answer (score 0):

I ended up fixing it, I made a call for the coredata object as a variable, then passed it through with a segue. then all i needed to do was make `selectedNote?.title = noteText.text`

This is the full complete code:

```
var selectedEvent: Event? = nil

@IBAction func textFieldEndEdit(_ sender: Any) {
        print("edit end")
        
          guard let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate else {
                    return
                }
                let context = appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext

                
                do {

                    
                    selectedEvent?.title = noteText.text
                    
                    do {
                        try context.save()
                    }
                    
                } catch {
                    let nserror = error as NSError
                    fatalError("Unresolved error \(nserror), \(nserror.userInfo)")
                }
        
    }
```